# Underlining the text in an submit button (html, css)

Tags: html, css, form-submit, hyperlink

I'm (probably unwisely) attempting to style an input submit button to make it look like a regular hyperlink. Using css everything is fine, except for the underlining, which is not being rendered. Css:

```
input.addemail { 
  border: 0px; 
  background-color: #1e2f45; 
  text-decoration: underline; 
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer; 
  color: #ffd17d; 
}
```

Is there a way to underline the text (value) of a submit button that'll work x-browser? Or is there another approach - e.g use an image? Obviously I'd like a good guarantee that whatever approach is used it'll work x-browser, inc. ie6 :). Or is this just futile??

Another approach would be to hide the button and use a hyperlink which when clicked would, in javascript, submit the form. But I understand that there may be issues with the user expecting to be able to hit return, which may not work if the button is hidden.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I had the same trouble, and after googling, I found an answer that works for me

```
input {
    text-decoration:underline;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The solution with more examples belongs to Mike Ballan, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120420000031/http://www.wtfdwk.com/input-underlined-text-not-working/).

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `text-decoration` for the button, as an alternative, you can mimic the similar behaviour with border property like this:

```
border-bottom:1px solid #1e2f45;
```

Comment: Nice suggestion - but there's a bit of a gap between the line and the text. I've set padding: 0 and appropriate line height but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a `<span>` to simulate a hyperlink, and actually call a JavaScript function, which you could of course then underline.

Comment: My takeaway from this post, working like a charm. GJ Fiona!

Answer (score 0):

If you move the submit button off-screen you can then use the A link for the nicely-styled button as well as have the "press return" functionality.

You can use various CSS tricks, including "margin-left:-9999".